# Finding closest matches (by distance metric) in two batches of pytorch tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to find the closest matches between two batches of pytorch tensors. Assuming I have a batch of `mxn` tensors with batch size `b1` and a batch of `mxn` tensors  with batch size `b2`, I would like to find:

- The distance between each `mxn` tensor in batch `b1` and each `mxn` tensor in batch `b2`.  This distance matrix would be of size `b1xb2`.
- For each tensor in `b1`, I would like the batch index of the closest (by distance) tensor in `b2`.

I define distance as the sum of the elementwise squared Euclidean distance between corresponding elements in each tensor. For example, if the first tensor in `b1` (i.e. batch index = 0) is `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i], [j, k, l]]` and the first tensor in `b2` (i.e. batch index = 0) is `[[z, y, x], [w, v, u], [t, s, r]]`, then the distance between `b1` and `b2` is: (a-z)^2 + (b-y)^2 + (c-x)^2 + (d-w)^2 + (e-v)^2 +(f-u)^2 +...+(l-r)^2

Here's what I have tried:

```
a = torch.rand((3, 3, 4))
b = torch.rand((5, 3, 4))
flat_a = torch.flatten(a, start_dim = 1)
flat_b = torch.flatten(b, start_dim = 1)
torch.cdist(flat_a, flat_b)
```

Which gives me a `3x5` matrix that I hope is correct. And I would now like to return the batch indices of the `3x4` tensors in `b` that are the closest matches to the tensors in `a`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the distance tensor `dist`. All you have to do is:

```
b_idx = torch.argmin(dist,dim = 1) # returns tensor of shape [3]
```

which returns the indices into `b` along dimension 0.